# ADF in flatbed scanner

Tags: java, scanning

Wee are using Jimageconnect java API to scan files from different devices. with single feeder scanners like HP scanjet 3000 everything is ok, but with the HP scanjet 7500 (which has ADF AND glass surface) we cant get scanned images from the ADF (just from the glass surface), is there any other java API to access ADF from this kind of flatbed scanners?

Comment: What is ADF? I was thinking it refers to a framework technology...

Comment: Automatic Document Feeder http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_document_feeder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

To access scanner through TWAIN:  http://asprise.com/product/jtwain/

and this will allow you to do ADF scanning in Java through WIA: http://asprise.com/product/jia

As you mentioned the second scanner has two functional units - flatbed and feeder, you need to select the second functional unit before calling ADF.

*Disclaimer: I work for the company that offer the above mentioned products.*